# how to change the height of a angular material button to fit it's text

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

When changing the size of the text inside of a mat-button, the width of the button changes along side it but the height stays static, I think the problem might be how I'm approaching this problem.

I'm changing the size of the text by adding a `font-size:300%;` styling to the button.

Comment: I think your looking for something like height: auto.

Comment: height: auto didn't fix the issue for me but adding padding to both the top and bottom fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my issue came from mat-button not having top or bottom padding when the text got scaled, adding:

```
padding-top: 16px;
padding-bottom: 16px;
```

Fixed the issue